# How do i connect to mailserver?

Tags: mail-server

i'm trying to create a contact form,with a code from a website,but when i open it with localhost,it give me an error:

```
   Warning: mail(): Failed to connect to mailserver at &quot;localhost&quot; port 25, verify your &quot;SMTP&quot; and &quot;smtp_port&quot; setting in php.ini or use ini_set() in D:\programe\wamp\www\website\trimite.php on line 41
```

Well,this is the line 41:

```
    mail($catre, $subiect, $mesaj, $headere);
```

It is anything wrong? Maybe it's because i need a database,or i dont know,im not really good at this.

Comment: You're trying to access a local SMTP server on port 25. Are you running an SMTP server on your computer? If not, you need to find a server to test against and configure your program accordingly.

Comment: well,do you know how i can do a SMTP server?

Comment: No I don't, but that's far outside the scope of Stack Overflow, anyway.

Comment: Well, you could start by Googling to find out what an SMTP server is and why you need one. Then you could Google to see if you can find one that suits your needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably this is way too old, but since I have an easy fix (I guess) I will give it a shot:

If you only want to try the code (mail function) and see if the email is actually sent, in your dev environment, you can try to accomplish that with this small tool: http://www.toolheap.com/test-mail-server-tool/

I used it several times in the past when I had no proper smtp mail server configuration available and I had to test in a few seconds that my code was behaving properly.

I hope it helps.